# Laravel Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::privilege()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to display `privileges('name')` instead of `idPrivilege` in the user collection. I have tried to add a relationship and use it in an Eloquent call but I'm getting an error.

**User model**

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $primaryKey = 'idUser';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'updated_at',
    ];

    public function privilege()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Privilege::class, 'idPrivilege', 'idPrivilege');
    }
}
```

**Privilege model**

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Privilege extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'privileges';

    protected $primaryKey = 'idPrivilege';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'updated_at', 
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'idPrivilege', 'idPrivilege');
    }
}
```

**UserController**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function relationTest()
    {
        return User::where('idUser', 1)->privilege()->get();
    }
}
```

I'm getting the below error when I use `with('privilege')` to my User collection is added privilege collection.

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::privilege().

Comment: Please can you show what you're expected output is?

Comment: in answer below i show the output i expect

Answer (score 0):

`where` returns a `Builder` instance on which a `privilege` method does not exist, so you can simply use it as such:

```
return User::find(1)->privilege()->get();;
```

-- EDIT

```
User::find(1)->with(['privilege' => function($query) { 
   $query->select('name');
}])->get();
```

Comment: It returns : [
{
"idPrivilege": 1,
"name": "user",
"created_at": "2019-05-04 12:56:55"
}
] and yes i have user in db with idPrivilege (1)

Comment: and what do you expect to be returned? That's the privilege object in json format.

Comment: User object with replaced idPrivilege to privilege (name of idPrivilege), {
"idUser": 1,
"name": "Martin",
"email": "martin@martin.martin",
"idPrivilege": 1,
"created_at": "2019-05-04 12:11:43"
} => {
"idUser": 1,
"name": "Martin",
"email": "martin@martin.martin",
"privilege": "user",
"created_at": "2019-05-04 12:11:43"
}

Answer (score 0):

I can achieve it by using resource:

```
$user = User::where('idUser', 1)->with('privilege')->first();
return UserResource::make($user);
```

Inside UserResource:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'idUser' => $this->idUser,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'privilege' => $this->privilege['name'],
        'createdAt' => $this->created_at,
    ];
}
```

but was hoping there is simplier method of getting that.

output:

```
{
"data": {
"idUser": 1,
"name": "Martin",
"email": "martin@martin.martin",
"privilege": "user",
"createdAt": "2019-05-05T01:11:43.000000Z"
}
}
```